# Can't pull Google+ API data with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-plus

I have been messing with this for weeks and I still havent come up with a solution. My goal is to

- authenticate a user
- pull and display their google+ api data

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to adapt the google+ ruby sample code given by google, but that didn't work correctly for me. I used that as a basis for writing my own however. So far I have this:

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'

$credentials = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load

# Initialize the client.
$authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :authorization_uri => $credentials.authorization_uri,
    :token_credential_uri => $credentials.token_credential_uri,
    :client_id => $credentials.client_id,
    :client_secret => $credentials.client_secret,
    :redirect_uri => $credentials.redirect_uris.first,
    :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')

@client = Google::APIClient.new(
    :application_name => 'X', #havent changed this at all
    :application_version => 'X' #havent changed this at all
    )

@client.authorization.update_token!(:access_token => 'X', :refresh_token => 'X')#havent changed this at all

# Initialize Google+ API. Note this will make a request to the
# discovery service every time, so be sure to use serialization
# in your production code. Check the samples for more details.
@plus = @client.discovered_api( "plus", "v1" )

# Make an API call.
@google_plus_info = @client.execute(
    :api_method => @plus.activities.list,
    :parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'VALID USER ID HERE'} #I masked my own userid which I am using for testing
    )
render plain: "api call:\n#{@google_plus_info.data.title}"
end
end
```

My api explorer output was:

```
{
"kind": "plus#activityFeed",
"etag": "\"BLAHBLAH\"",
"title": "Google+ List of Activities for Collection PUBLIC",
"updated": "2013-02-02T02:54:10.697Z",
....
```

so I assumed I would have no problem displaying the title value. My output is blank however (except for the words api call:) What am I missing?

Comment: You're using rails 4.1.x?

Comment: Yes, I am using Rails 4.1.5. Also testing in Chrome with no extensions.